# How to make graphics/curves?

Tags: android, graph

I have some data stored, and want to display them as a graph like this:

[image: http://lh6.ggpht.com/Kzi6oBWH4HsPJPSiQhWiDWXnBy8NANz7m5SVW7iOtI3wBoPg_IiK9Aa8Dv8QJIipzLrtvrw3P1ZL5UZnZw=s128-c]

How to make/build that? I really need this feature in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the accepted answer of this [so-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android)

link-summary of that post:

1. [rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing](http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing)
2. [GraphView](http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview)
3. [Java Charts for Android](http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=android)
4. [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/wiki/Screenshots)
5. [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home)
6. [AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Sample Project](https://github.com/blessenm/LineChartDemo) I made. This might give you an idea what you need to do.

Comment: So i have to use 2 classes to obtain a curve ?

Comment: 1 class file is an activity. LineChartView is a custom view created to make the chart. There are libraries that give a lot of options like in the other answer. But if what you need is simple, this will be enough.

Comment: In your project, the values are pre-defined. For mine, i have to browse file values then extract them then display them in chart. That will be difficult :\.

Comment: This is not a complete solution. Will only give you an idea on how to do your project. I created this to use for my project which had values coming from a socket. The predefined aray was to create an example. There is a setData method for that view. Like I said, this is just a reference of how to draw, the rest is upto you. Or you think thats too hard, you'll need to go with the different charting libraries.